# Stepwizards in a laravel app

Tags: jquery, laravel, wizard

Please I want to use a step wizard in my UI with laravel and Jquery. 
The problem is in each step interface I have a form with at least 3 or 4 commom fields with the same validator error. 
**The problem is:** I am in the first step and wwhen I submit the form ( in the first step) I see the other form which is in the other step also validated although i have disabled it.

Can anyone help me how to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Good question, I would also like to know how to fix this. Maybe sharing some code would be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I haven't already solved the problem.